# PySide/PyQt Signal sent when highlighting text in QTextBrowser

Tags: pyqt, pyside, qtextbrowser

Is there a signal that is sent by QTextBrowser when highlighting text?

```
self.textBrowser.highlighted.connect(self.test)

def test(self,argv_1):
   print('This Worked')
```

When I tried this the signal didn't seem to be sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`highlighted`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtextbrowser.html#highlighted) signal is emitted when an *anchor* in the text is highlighted, it doesn't fire when text is selected.

If you're interested in in changes of the selection, use the [`selectionChanged`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtextedit.html#selectionChanged) signal (inherited from `QTextEdit`)

Comment: I see, thanks! But could you tell me what an 'anchor' is? I might actually make use of it.

Comment: _anchor_ as in html anchor: `<a href="...">...</a>`